# How to report on serialized data in a custom field on Opportunities?

Tags: reporting, opportunity, custom-reports

I added a custom field (Long text )to Opportunities called 'Month_Breakdown'. It carries data like: 'Jan=10000&Feb=50000&Jun=20000&Dec=89000'. I would like to have a report that shows opportunities grouped by Month. Hopefully which I can export later as a PDF or excel.  Please take a look at screen shot. 
[image]

Basically would like to go through all the opportunities and present the report. So far I created a custom report with 'Opportunities' as the primary object. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi kratos, we don't really cover Excel here, but I am sure we can help you sort out a Salesforce Reporting issue. Could you please [edit] your question to clarify in *words* what you want your report to do, and how this custom field you've mentioned goes into it? At first blush it sounds like you may want a Matrix Report with groupings by Close Date and Stage.

Comment: Hi @DavidReed . The report does not need to be in excel. Just need that data so I can hopefully export it as a PDF or excel. I'll edit my question further however.

Comment: if the month totals are in a single custom field; you should write a VF page/controller that queries the Opportunities, unpacks the custom field into a collection and then renders the result for excel or pdf.  This will work if you don't have too many Oppos as there will be Heap limitations, collection size limitations, and max rows limitations